# Unity 2D When Zoom In Scene Disappears

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, editor

So I zoomed out really far yesterday, just fidgeting. Today when I try to zoom in the scene just disappears. I have looked this up and tried using F like they said to. But clicking F did not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click on one of your gameobjects in the hierarchy view.